# Running mongod.exe from webstorm

Tags: mongodb, webstorm

It's an extremely simple question but can anyone kindly tell me how can I start mongod.exe from Webstorm instead of from Command Prompt?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like there's a nice Webstorm plugin for this [here](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7141).